# Creating PDF file in VBA code causes Access to crash/close

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access 2016 application that contains a report which needs to be saved as a PDF file. Whenever the user presses the button that does the output to PDF the application closes without warning (crashes). Any idea what could cause this?

The VBA code called by the button press looks like this:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "MyReport", acFormatPDF, "\\myserver\myfolder\myfilename.pdf"
```

Comment: Cannot replicate issue. Even without closing quote mark (testing in Immediate window), I still get the PDF output. VBA procedure also works (it automatically adds the missing quote).

Comment: It's driving me crazy because it happens all the time on some users' computers, and only intermittently on mine! And I can't trap for any error because Access simply closes without warning....argh!

Comment: Does the application include `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` ?

Comment: No Hans. One other thing...after the crash I find a file named something like msoCFE.tmp leftover in the destination folder. I imagine Access builds a temp file as it's outputting the report, and when it's done it renames it to myfilename.pdf, and somewhere during this process it's crashing...but why???

Comment: Can the user create the PDF somewhere on their local drive without error/crash?

Comment: Hi Hans....that's what I'm trying now...I'll report back!

Comment: Are there instances where the file path is very long?  I know I've had issues saving from Excel VBA where the file path ends up being more than 256 characters.

Comment: Do you have a split database - or is everyone sharing the code db? Is there possibility that two users could be trying to write to same filename at the same time?

Comment: No, dbmitch, only one person ever uses this application at a time. And Steve, I'm checking that now, seems to be intermittent, but the file paths can get a bit long...I haven't found a specific limit in the cases I've tested, though.

Comment: Is this using runtime by any chance? Any un handled error in a accDB used with runtime will shut down. if you compile to a accDE, then no such shutdown will occur with runtime. If you not using runtime version of access then my comments don't apply.

Comment: Thank you, Albert. We have the same issue when using access runtime. the application always works correctly when on a full Access version. I will try accDE and give an update.